# How to display Dynamic Object Arrays into chart using Anychart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, anychart

What i am trying to do is i want to display a chart based on my dynamic data i used Angular ForEach to loop through all my objects array see my code below:

```
var parse = JSON.parse(jsondata);

angular.forEach(parse, function (value, key) {
  var dataSet = anychart.data.set(value);
  var chart = anychart.column();
  var series = chart.column(value);
  chart.title("Data Sets: Array of Objects");
  chart.container("container");
  chart.draw();
});
```

it correctly display the count of my chart but the data of each object array is not showing up see picture below

[image]

but if put a static data like this :

```
var data = [
    {x:"January", value: 12000},
    {x:"February", value:  15000},
    {x:"March", value:  16000},
    {x:"April", value:  14000},
    {x:"May", value:  10000}
  ];
```

the chart displays correctly.

can anyone help me with this ? any help will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Everything depends on the `value` content inside the loop. You are applying the `value` to the series and dataSet as well.
If you are using dataSet, you should apply the `value` to the dataSet, map the data, then apply the mapping to the series. Like this:

```
  var dataSet = anychart.data.set(value);
  var mapping = dataSet.mapAs({'x': 0, 'value': 1}); // for example
  var chart = anychart.column();
  var series = chart.column(dataSet);
```

The mapping depends on your data. If the `value` includes ready-to-use data that matches the default mapping you can apply it directly to the series.

Can you share the `value` content?

Comment: Thanks for the response , As you can see the data on my value is the same as the static data . 0: {Description: "Male", COUNT: 100, PERCENTAGE: 20}
1: {Description: "Female", COUNT: 300, PERCENTAGE: 80}
2: {Description: "TOTAL", COUNT: 400, PERCENTAGE: 100}

Comment: However as what you've said i should map for the proper series and dataSet but i have a dynamic series and dataset ? the scenario is  ill be displaying 5 dynamic charts with different Series and DataSet from value data how would be able to achieve this ?

Comment: "Description", "COUNT" and "PERCENTAGE" fields are not the defaults ones. So, the chart can't recognize the data mapping. You should map manually the data in this case. For details check the sample - https://playground.anychart.com/fmcq2WKT

Comment: The chart can work with dynamic data. All you need is to apply new data to the existing dataSet. There's no need to recreate chart/series/mapping or anything else. Simply execute the following when you need:
```

```

Comment: thanks for the response again . however if ill do this ? what if  ? if the series for my 2nd chart is different from the existing series 'X' that i map/define before in my data set ?

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't get your idea correctly. You can create the mapping for every series individually. Also, you can change mapping at every moment.

Answer (score 0):

The chart can work with dynamic data. All you need is to apply new data to the existing dataSet, like this:

```
dataSet.data(newData);
```

And that's it! There's no need to recreate chart/series/dataSet.

Comment: Hi As iv'e try what your suggesting looks like the down side of mapping is you'll be having a default 'x' series and 'value' to get the data for your dataset . however can i ask a favor ? can you create a sample code in playground.anychart that will display two the same chart but different series 'X' and 'value' ?  using the code you provide ? which is dataSet.data(newData)  greatly appreciated your reply thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't understand your requirements. Two identical charts from different data? Or do you want to store different X fields and values fields for two series in one dataset? If you can share the data you want to visualize it will help us a lot. Please, contact us support@anychart.com