# Anychart.js Display data dynamically

Tags: angular, anychart

I'm trying to draw a timeline chart with data that I get from a database by using anychart v8 and Angular CLI v10.0.4
I saw this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58498260/how-to-display-dynamic-object-arrays-into-chart-using-anychart-js), which is very similar to my problem here. I followed the steps but I can't see the data. And I get this error : Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "M NaN 56.5 L NaN 5…".
I tried to hardcode the data, and then it worked just fine, so I don't know what went wrong.

Here's how I get the data with Sequelize :

```js
exports.getAllStoryArcs = (req, res, next) => {
    StoryArc.findAll({
        include: [StoryArc.startChapter, StoryArc.endChapter],
        order: [['startChapter', 'number', 'ASC']]
    })
            .then((storyArcs) => {
                res.status(200).json(storyArcs);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(400).json({
                    error: err
                })
            });
};
```

EDIT : Here's a sample of the data get from MySQL DB with Sequelize :

```js
[
  Story Arc {
    dataValues: {
      id: 6,
      name: "Introduction",
      synopsis: "synopsis text",
      delailedSummary: "detailedSummary text",
      createdAt: 2020-08-22T16:41:21.000Z,
      updatedAt: 2020-08-22T16:41:21.000Z,
      startChapterId: 1,
      endChapterId: 8,
      startChapter: {
        id: 1,
        number: 1,
        title: "title text",
        synopsis: "synopsis text"
      },
      endChapter: {
        id: 8,
        number: 8,
        title: "title text",
        synopsis: "synopsys text"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Here's my data transformation function (data.service.ts) :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { StoryArcService } from './story-arc.service';
import { StoryArcDTO } from '../models/story-arc-dto.model';
const BASE_YEAR: number = 2000;
const START_MONTH: number = 0;
const END_MONTH: number = 11;
const START_DAY: number = 1;
const END_DAY: number = 31;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
/**
* Service class to manage the timeline chart's data.
*/
export class DataService {
  
  // Array of arcs
  private _arcs: Array<StoryArcDTO>;
  // The arcs mapped to be use in the timeline chart
  private _arcsMap: Array<Object> = [];
  // The set to use in the chart
  private _arcsSet: anychart.data.Set;
  
  constructor(private arcService: StoryArcService) {
    this.setArcData();
  }
  
  private setArcData() {
    // Fill the array of story arcs
    this.arcService.getAllArcs().subscribe(
      gottenArcs => {
        if (gottenArcs) {
          this._arcs = gottenArcs;
          // Fill the anychart data set
          this._arcs.forEach((arc) => {
            // Map the arc data set
            this._arcsMap.push({
              name: arc.name,
              start: Date.UTC(BASE_YEAR + arc.startChapter.number, START_MONTH, START_DAY),
              end: Date.UTC(BASE_YEAR + arc.endChapter.number, END_MONTH, END_DAY),
              startNb: arc.startChapter.number,
              endNb: arc.endChapter.number
            });
          });
        }
      }
    );
  }
  
  public get arcsMap() : Object[] {
    return this._arcsMap;
  }
}
```

EDIT 2 : I do have done the mapping but it doesn't work. After the mapping, it looks like this :

```js
[
   {name: "Introduction", start: Date.UTC(2001, 0, 1), end: Date.UTC(2008, 11, 31), startNb: 1, endNb: 8},
   {name: "Révolution chez les princesses", start: Date.UTC(2009, 0, 1), end: Date.UTC(2014, 11, 31), startNb: 9, endNb: 14},
   {name: "La formule magique de l'ange", start: Date.UTC(2015, 0, 1), end: Date.UTC(2019, 11, 31), startNb: 15, endNb: 19}
]
```

And then my component (timelines.component.js):

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'anychart';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-timelines',
  templateUrl: './timelines.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timelines.component.css']
})
export class TimelinesComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public initTimeline: anychart.charts.Timeline;
  public globalTimeline: anychart.charts.Timeline;
  public globalRange: anychart.core.timeline.series.Range;
  
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initChart();
  }
  
  initChart() {
    console.log(this.dataService.arcsMap);
    let arcsSet = anychart.data.set(this.dataService.arcsMap);
    
    this.globalTimeline = anychart.timeline();
    this.globalTimeline.axis().height(20);
    this.globalTimeline.axis().fill("#7030A0");
    this.globalTimeline.axis().stroke("#381850");
    this.globalTimeline.axis().ticks().stroke("#AB74D5");
    this.globalTimeline.axis().labels().fontFamily("Ubuntu");
    this.globalTimeline.axis().labels().fontWeight("bold");
    this.globalTimeline.axis().labels().fontColor("#E3D1F1");
    this.globalTimeline.axis().labels().format(function() {
      let realNumber = this.value;
      if (realNumber >= BASE_YEAR) {
        realNumber = this.value - BASE_YEAR;
      }
      return realNumber;
    })
    
    this.globalRange = this.globalTimeline.range(arcsSet);
    
    this.globalRangeSettings();
    
    this.globalTimeline.container("global-timeline");
    this.globalTimeline.draw();      
  }
  
  globalRangeSettings() {
    this.globalRange.height(30);
    this.globalRange.labels().format("{%name}");
    this.globalRange.labels().fontFamily("Ubuntu");
    this.globalRange.tooltip().titleFormat("{%name}");
    this.globalRange.tooltip().fontFamily("Ubuntu");
    this.globalRange.tooltip().format(function() {
      return `Début : Chapitre ${this.getData("startNb")}
              Fin : Chapitre ${this.getData("endNb")}`;
    })
    this.globalRange.color("#8E44BD");
  }
}
```

I verified, and I get the data as I want them in the initChart function, but the draw function seems not to understand them or something.

Could someone help me please ?

Comment: The error you get tells that chart can render correctly the applied data. It means that data is not valid or includes misconfiguration. Can you provide the `this.dataService.arcsMap` content to review and reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi ! I added it to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I followed what @AnyChart Support said about the timing of fetching data.

I got rid of my data service class, I transformed the data in the timelines component, and I added the async keyword to my iniChart method, and so it works !

I don't really understand why though XD

the result looks like this :

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initChart();
}
    
async initChart() {
    let arcsSet = anychart.data.set(await this.setArcData());
        
    this.globalTimeline = anychart.timeline();
    this.globalTimeline.axis().height(20);
    this.globalTimeline.axis().fill("#7030A0");
    this.globalTimeline.axis().stroke("#381850");
    this.globalTimeline.axis().ticks().stroke("#AB74D5");
    this.globalTimeline.axis().labels().fontFamily("Ubuntu");
    this.globalTimeline.axis().labels().fontWeight("bold");
    this.globalTimeline.axis().labels().fontColor("#E3D1F1");
    this.globalTimeline.axis().labels().format(function() {
        let realNumber = this.value;
        if (realNumber >= BASE_YEAR) {
            realNumber = this.value - BASE_YEAR;
        }
        return realNumber;
    });
        
    this.globalRange = this.globalTimeline.range(arcsSet);
        
    this.globalRangeSettings();
        
    this.globalTimeline.container("global-timeline");
    this.globalTimeline.draw();      
}
      
globalRangeSettings() {
    this.globalRange.height(30);
    this.globalRange.labels().format("{%name}");
    this.globalRange.labels().fontFamily("Ubuntu");
    this.globalRange.tooltip().titleFormat("{%name}");
    this.globalRange.tooltip().fontFamily("Ubuntu");
    this.globalRange.tooltip().format(function() {
        return `Début : Chapitre ${this.getData("startNb")}
                Fin : Chapitre ${this.getData("endNb")}`;
        })
    this.globalRange.color("#8E44BD");
}
      
async setArcData(): Promise<Object[]> {
    this.arcs = await this.arcService.getAllArcs().toPromise();
    let result: Object[] = [];
    this.arcs.forEach(arc => {
        result.push({
            name: arc.name,
            start: Date.UTC(BASE_YEAR + arc.startChapter.number, START_MONTH, START_DAY),
            end: Date.UTC(BASE_YEAR + arc.endChapter.number, END_MONTH, END_DAY),
            startNb: arc.startChapter.number,
            endNb: arc.endChapter.number
        });
    });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data content doesn't meet the required data format of the chart. You can preprocess it or apply a specified mapping to let the chart parse your data correctly. You can find the required data format in [the article](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Timeline_Chart#data). [The sample](https://playground.anychart.com/U1OVhYyf) describes how to apply mapping to the Timeline chart.

Comment: I did the mapping, that what I do when I fill the arcsMap. I've edit my post to show the result of the mapping, but it doesn't work and I get the error.

Comment: The data you provided in the last edit works well - https://playground.anychart.com/0d50n22z
Can you provide the full chart configuration code?

Comment: Yeah, and that is my problem =/ When I hardcode them, there's no problem but when I get them from the database, it doesn't work. I edit the post with all my to classes (data.service.ts and timelines.component.ts) and I added the sequelize method that get all the arcs

Comment: The chart configuration code is absolutely correct. It requires debugging the moment when the data is applied to the data set in a real application. Probably data is not fetched yet or smth else goes wrong.

Comment: Well, I'll try to debug that. Thank you for you're help though !